# Python Selenium ActionChains not working for Keys.ENTER

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium on a webpage with a search bar. Unfortunately the search bar's HTML `input tag` does not have the *id* attribute. So I used the following code to enter text into the search bar:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys('mytext')
actions.perform()
```

Next, I want to press the ENTER key, but that's where my code is not working. I tried using:

- `actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`
- `actions.send_keys('mytext'+Keys.ENTER)`
- `actions.send_keys('mytext'+u'\ue007')`

But none of it is simulating the ENTER key.
I also tried using `find_element` and select but both result in an error that the element is not interactable. Is there any other way I can get this done i.e. enter the text and press enter?

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate enter key press while sending the keys itself.

so instead of

```
actions.send_keys('mytext')
```

use this:

```
actions.send_keys('mytext', Keys.RETURN)
```

**Import:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Comment: It's still not working. ENTER is not getting simulated

Comment: What's the error did you get ?

Comment: there is no error. On ENTER, it should go to the next page, but it does not happen in this case

Comment: Is it possible to share page url ?

Comment: Due to some restrictions, the page URL cannot be shared.